# How to find the difference between 3 lists that may have duplicate numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 3 lists and I want to find the difference between the 1st/2nd and 2nd/3rd 
and print them.

Here is my code:

```
n1 = [1,1,1,2,3] 
n2 = [1,1,1,2] # Here the 3 is not found ("3" is not present in n1 at all)
n3 = [1,1,2]   # here 1 is not found (there are fewer "1"s in n3 than in n2)
for x in n1: 
   if x not in n2:
      print x  
for m in n2: 
   if m not in n3: 
      print m
```

but i get only 3 as output.

How to make it output 1 and 3? I tried using `set`s as well, but it only printed `3` again.

Comment: @bkaf Curious to which of those solutions applies here, as they all involve using sets, which quite obviously isn't applicable to this question.

Comment: please help me or tell me how to  solve it or in what i search and thank you i search many times

Comment: i try use sets and the same problem only output 3 only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you seem to care about the number of times an item is found in both lists, you need to either remove matched items from the list you're comparing with:

```
comp = n2[:]  # make a copy
for x in n1:
    if x not in comp:
        print x
    else:
        comp.remove(x)
# output: 3
```

or use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter(n1) - Counter(n2)
# output: Counter({3: 1})
```

which tells you which items in `n1` are not in `n2` or can be found more often in `n1` than in `n2`.

So, for example:

```
>>> Counter([1,2,2,2,3]) - Counter([1,2])
Counter({2: 2, 3: 1})
```

Comment: I didn't know there was a `__sub__` for `Counter` objects. That's pretty neat.

Answer (score -3):

you can use set to find the difference between list.

```
print set(n1).difference(set(n2))
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It doesn't get the second case where there is an extra `1` in `n2`

Comment: yeah I agree. it gets the difference as a whole and does not consider repetitions as unique